# No idea why Cent OS disk fills up, yum clean all fixes

Tags: nginx, centos, yum, diskspace

I'm having some trouble with a Cent OS 7 box.

The problems just started last week and I have made no changes to the server.

The disk keeps filling up several times a day from 83% to 100%.

As soon as it is full, Nginx can't generate full webpages.

If I run "yum clean all" the disk goes back to 83% and everything runs fine again.

I'm not run daily yum updates, so I'm not sure why "yum clean all" fixes it.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot and stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the yum-cron package which check daily (with /etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron) for updates and download them by default.

In /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf you have by default :

```
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = no
```

You can configure yum-cron to apply them, or send you an email so you can apply them manually and clean instead of re-downloading each update daily after previous clean.

You can use tools such as http://diskreport.net to diagnose where you space usage grow between two dates

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a cron job to delete the files and folders through a cron every hour i.e.

```
Login as root

crontab -e

# Every hour
0 * * * * /bin/rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

Comment: A daily or weekly `yum clean all` would likely be a better choice.